# Convert string received from BTSerial to HEX string

Tags: c++, arduino, bluetooth, microcontroller, esp32

I have an App where I send Hex-Strings to my ESP32. I would like these strings, as they are, to be sent via an RS232 to TTL module, that is connected to my ESP, to a scaler.

On my App side I am sending this command:

```
"\\e\\x34\\x54\\x45\\x53\\x54\\r" //This translates to ascii ESC4TESTCarriageReturn
```

It needs double escaped characters in order to actually send a single backslash.

On my microcontroller side I am doing:

```
//This reads the incoming BT message
String message = SerialBT.readStringUntil('\n');
//This sends the message, converted to a char * 
Serial2.write(message.c_str());
```

In theory, I am receiving the correct string as you can see in the serial monitor output:

```
BT Message received: \e\x34\x54\x45\x53\x54\r
The command to be sent via rs232: \e\x34\x54\x45\x53\x54\r
Error: E10 //This indicates that the message could not be processed by the receiver
```

However, if I send the message staright up like this, predefined in my microcontroller code I get the correct response from the receiver:

```
Serial2.write("\e\x34\x54\x45\x53\x54\r");

------ Output ------
Test4 //This indicates that Testpattern 4 was selected
```

I am not that familiar with c++ so I am probably doing something obviously wrong, maybe anyone knows, how I can convert the received BT-Message to an actual message that can be sent over Serial2.

Edit: So basically my question is, how can I achieve a transaltion of the string that I am receiving via bluetooth **(\e\x34\x54\x45\x53\x54\r)** to be converted as it is, into a Hex-string that is interpreted correctly by the microcontroller and is therefore correctly sent over rs232.

Comment: Quite simply, [the strings are not equal](https://godbolt.org/z/qbqb1qo3a).  This: `"\e\x34\x54\x45\x53\x54\r"` contains actual hexadecimal numbers, not characters.  That's what the `\x` does.

Comment: You are right, but as the serial output indicates, I am receiving the right string, with only one backslash. I assume it just interprets it as a complete string and the one that I defined in my cpp code is actually interpreted as hex characters. So do you know how I can achieve a translation or conversion?

Comment: Somehow you have to take what you have in `message.c_str()` and figure out how to transform it to get the string that actually worked.  You can start by [breaking down exactly what you have](https://godbolt.org/z/5dK4hsKso) and see what the characters are.  Note -- you cannot just use console output to debug this -- you need to see *exactly*, character by character, what `message.c_str()` has.  As far as I know, it could even contain control characters that are invisible in the console.

Comment: The `92` is the backslash character, so the string with double backslashes has absolutely no hexadecimal numbers in it.  It is just plain old character data, for example `x`,`3`,`4`.  The string you say worked actually does have hexadecimal data in it, which is why the `test2` string at the godbolt link, when broken down, is much shorter.

Comment: You are mixing the representation of strings in source code with actual strings. Since there is no built-in runtime parser, did you consider to write your own?

Comment: Excately, I already thought so, that they are interpreted differently. But my question is exactely this: How can I achieve a conversion from the string that is sent, 1:1 to an actual hex string that is interpreted (or sent) correctly. I tried looking things up but couldn't really find much.

Comment: @CaptainAllergy -- *I tried looking things up* -- I think you need to actually write the code to parse the string and create a new string that is compatible.  Since I am more familiar with `std::string` and standard C++, I don't know what facilities are offered by arduino, but it shouldn't be anything radically different than writing a function that takes in a "bad" string, and creates the good string and returns the good string.

Comment: For example, [this standard C++ solution gets the right data](https://godbolt.org/z/z6rsYxqGK), but this is basically ad-hoc code written to fit your data, and again, I don't know if arduino has the functionality built into their C++ standard to use `stringstream` or not.  So YMMV.

Comment: Do you need to send backslashes? I guess you don't, so `std::string message("\e\x34\x54\x45\x53\x54\r");` should be enough, as it contains only hex values.

Comment: Thanks for the provided solutions I will test them out. Mybe I need to clarify the double backslasehs. They are sent on the app side, because the Kotlin compiler interprets a single backslash as an escape character. The compiler ignores one backslash during runtime and sends only one backslash via bluetooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to write an own parser. Since you say you control the BT sender side, you don't need *all* of the common capabilities of the C++ standard.

We see these different kinds of substrings for single characters:

- `"\e"` for `'\e'`;
- `"\x##"` for `'\x##'`, "##" being a two-digit hex number;
- `"\r"` for `'\r'`.

This is a small test sketch for a straight-forward solution:

```cpp
void setup() {
  while (!Serial);
  String message = "\\e\\x34\\x54\\x45\\x53\\x54\\r";
  Serial.println(message);
  String toSend = unescape(message);
  for (int c : toSend) {
    Serial.print(c, HEX);
  }
  Serial.println();
}

void loop() {
}

String unescape(String &escaped) {
  String unescaped;
  for (size_t index = 0; index < escaped.length(); index++) {
    if (escaped[index] == '\\') {
      index++;
      switch (escaped[index]) {
      case 'e':
        unescaped += '\e';
        break;
      case 'x':
        index++;
        {
          char hex = strtol(escaped.substring(index, index + 2).c_str(), 0, 16);
          unescaped += hex;
        }
        index++;
        break;
      case 'r':
        unescaped += '\r';
        break;
      default:
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return unescaped;
}
```

Please note that this simple suggestion has some minor issues you don't want in professional software:

- It does no error checks in `unescape()`. Actually, it silently returns an incomplete or erroneous result, if the input has errors.
- It uses Arduino's `String` that is slow and bulky.

Use it as a starting point for your own better solution.

Comment: Your code works like a charm. Just adding an error check if any incorrect string has been sent. In fact, I don't even need the special characters like \e and \r since I can just simply send the corresponding hex encoding \x1B and \x0D. Thanks for the input!

Comment: And be aware that you cannot send `'\x00'`. ;-)